# How to disable App Sugestion bar in my App menu?

Tags: google-apps, 7.1-nougat

I searched in lot of places but there are only solution for Marshmallow or lower SDK, I'm looking a solution for 7.1.1

Answer (score 0):

Are you running stock? If yes go to Google app -> Settings (left panel) then at the bottom there's an option for turning suggested apps on or off.